# switching out useEffect for @tanstack/react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I recently decided to replace my useEffect data fetches over to react-query.

my useEffect works perfectly but when i try to convert my code directly for react-query i run into all kinds of issues.

Every example I have found online shows using Json CDNs or local JSON files as the data to use.

I am using firestore which is very specific about how it likes its data fetching.

Here is my useEffect working code...

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Virtual, Navigation, FreeMode } from "swiper";
import { SongCard } from "./Songcard";
import { db } from "../pages/api/auth/firebase/config";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import Link from "next/link";

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/virtual";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/free-mode";

export default function Slider() {
  const [songData, setSongData] = useState([]);
  /*   console.log(songData); */
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSongs = async () => {
      const colRef = collection(db, "songs");
      try {
        await getDocs(colRef).then((snapshot) => {
          let data = [];
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            data.push({
              ...doc.data(),
              songId: doc.id,
            });
            setSongData(data);
          });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };
    fetchSongs();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Swiper
      key={songData}
      //onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      modules={[Virtual, Navigation, FreeMode]}
      slidesPerView={6}
      slidesOffsetBefore={-106}
      virtual
      navigation={true}
      grabCursor={true}
      breakpoints={{
        280: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        350: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 50,
        },
        500: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        638: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
        },
        820: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        1060: {
          slidesPerView: 5,
        },

        1260: {
          slidesPerView: 6,
        },
      }}
    >
      {songData.map((song) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={song.songId}>
          <Link href={`/artist/${song.userId}`} passHref>
            <SongCard data={song} />
          </Link>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  );
}
```

I then moved the data fetch out to its own file as follows...

```
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../pages/api/auth/firebase/config";

const fetchSongs = async () => {
  const colRef = collection(db, "songs");
  try {
    await getDocs(colRef).then((snapshot) => {
      let data = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push({
          ...doc.data(),
          songId: doc.id,
        });
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};

export default fetchSongs;
```

And then added react-query to my Swiper component...

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Virtual, Navigation, FreeMode } from "swiper";
import { SongCard } from "./Songcard";
import { db } from "../pages/api/auth/firebase/config";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import fetchSongs from "../utils/getSongs";

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/virtual";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/free-mode";

export default function Slider() {
  const [songData, setSongData] = useState([]);

  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery("songs", fetchSongs());

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
  }

  setSongData(data);

  return (
    <Swiper
      key={songData}
      //onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      modules={[Virtual, Navigation, FreeMode]}
      slidesPerView={6}
      slidesOffsetBefore={-106}
      virtual
      navigation={true}
      grabCursor={true}
      breakpoints={{
        280: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        350: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 50,
        },
        500: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        638: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
        },
        820: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        1060: {
          slidesPerView: 5,
        },

        1260: {
          slidesPerView: 6,
        },
      }}
    >
      {songData.map((song) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={song.songId}>
          <Link href={`/artist/${song.userId}`} passHref>
            <SongCard data={song} />
          </Link>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  );
}
```

I now get the following errors...

[image]

Any advice on where I am going wrong please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Why do you call `fetchSongs` in the declaration file? 2. Why don't you call the function here `() => fetchSongs`? Should be `() => fetchSongs()`

Comment: Thanks, i now get the following though...
TypeError: (0 , _utils_getSongs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default) is not a function
    at Object.eval [as queryFn] (Slider.js?7489:19:74)
    at Object.fetchFn [as fn] (query.mjs?b252:249:1)
    at run (retryer.mjs?026a:97:1)
    at eval (retryer.mjs?026a:135:1)

Comment: You forgot to export `fetchSongs`

Comment: Should be `export default fetchSongs;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working as follows...

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Virtual, Navigation, FreeMode } from "swiper";
import { SongCard } from "./Songcard";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Link from "next/link";
import fetchSongs from "../utils/getSongs";

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/virtual";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/free-mode";

export default function Slider() {
  const [songData, setSongData] = useState([]);

  const { data, status } = useQuery(["songs"], fetchSongs, {
    staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "success") {
      setSongData(data);
    }
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <Swiper
      key={songData}
      //onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      modules={[Virtual, Navigation, FreeMode]}
      slidesPerView={6}
      slidesOffsetBefore={-106}
      virtual
      navigation={true}
      grabCursor={true}
      breakpoints={{
        280: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        350: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 50,
        },
        500: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        638: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
        },
        820: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        1060: {
          slidesPerView: 5,
        },

        1260: {
          slidesPerView: 6,
        },
      }}
    >
      {songData.map((song) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={song.songId}>
          <Link href={`/artist/${song.userId}`} passHref>
            <SongCard data={song} />
          </Link>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  );
}
```

And the fetch...

```
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../pages/api/auth/firebase/config";

export default async function fetchSongs() {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "songs"));
  const songs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  return songs;
}
```